# keep formula reference with indirect referring to cells in another worksheet after inserting rows

Tags: excel, vba, reference, formula

I have a workbook with several sheets and I want to refer to one cell's value in one worksheet on another worksheet. I done this using INDIRECT and works fine but my problem is when I insert rows in the source worksheet the INDIRECT formula "loses" the reference and keep the original cell address.
Any idea on how to do this???
Thanx in advance

Comment: Can you edit your question you include some examples of code and what your worksheet looks like?

Comment: I have in my workbook several sheets (1 for each moth and some others) and I need to display in one of them, let's say... kind of a monthly balance. I select the month with a dropdown and on each cell I have the appropiate INDIRECT function referring to the corresponding cell on each month. At this point everything is OK but when I insert some rows on every month the INDIRECT function remains the same cell reference and I need it to be updated every time I insert any row.